# How to delete a document within sub-collection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Firestore and currently, I am trying to delete a document which is located within a subcollection. For example, I am trying to delete the document KCF93F5 within a sub-collection called Ambulances in the image provided below[image]. How can I do this using javascript? Note: I am not using node js or any other framework

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the document in the subcollection by building the path using the IDs of the collections and documents (you fill them in as needed):

```
const ref = firestore.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).doc(...)
```

Then delete it with [delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#delete):

```
ref.delete()
```

`delete()` return a promise, so you should check it for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the document location and call delete which will return a promise :

```js
db.doc("/collection_1/collection_2/DC").delete().then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
});
```